# What does ganache mean by eth_getTransactionReceipt?

Tags: pending-transactions, ganache

I'm transitioning our testing suite from using the parity client to using ([a fork of](https://github.com/sc-forks/testrpc-sc/tree/coverage)) testrpc/ganache (so we can run code coverage). Our parity client has a lot of configuration, and I don't know how much of it needs to be equivalently configured in ganache. So far, when I run the testing suite, I see the following output from ganache;

```
<stuff about accounts>

net_version
eth_getTransactionCount
eth_sendRawTransaction
eth_getTransactionReceipt
eth_getTransactionReceipt
eth_getTransactionReceipt
...
<continues to print eth_getTransactionReceipt forever>
```

The testing command hangs here.

My question is; what does this mean? What are the possible states that the blockchain could be in, given that it gets to this point but no further?

Thus far, from reading through the source, my hypothesis is that the first transaction is sent, but it is not being mined into a block, and so no receipt is generated. But that leaves me with questions about why; is the transaction invalid? Or does the fact that it was sent mean that the client validated it? Is there a miner running by default? The docs make it sound like there is, but I don't know how to check.

Comment: It just runs things when you tell it to.  Not really a 'miner' but more of just accepts everything and puts it into a block.  You can force it to spit out blocks with the evm_mine specification.  More, but unfortunately little, info can be found here:  https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli